# Android ListView search and focus

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with names of people and an ActionBar with a Search widget.
What I want to do is focus the first item in the ListView that contains the search query as a substring.

For example if I have a person named "John Doe" and i search for "hn D" that row should be focused as long as it is the first one that contains "hn D" as a substring.

Note that I don't want the items that don't contain the substring removed from the list.

This is how I made the list.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
String[] names = {"John Doe","Mark Marky","Donald Duck","Derp Derpson"};
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.name, names);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I also have an action bar with the search widget and i implemented the `onQueryTextChange()` and `onQueryTextSubmit()` methods.

The question is how do I search through the list in those methods and how do I focus the appropriate list item?

Comment: Well, i'm not really sure, but I think that you can get the index for the first element that contains your search using `String.contains()` on each element of the `String[]`. If you get that index, you can use `mListView.requestFocus();` & `mListView.setSelection(position);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do textual search you can use a filter in your adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //do you work
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<Object> searchedList = new ArrayList<Object>();



            results.count = searchedList.size();
            results.values = searchedList;
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

}
```

and use it like that :

```
private void searchAction(String query) {
    youradapter.getFilter().filter(_query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

searchedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            YourActivity.this.youradapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        }
    });
```